# Run PowerShell script with PsExec and collect output objects

Tags: powershell, winrm

From remote PowerShell, I need to run a PowerShell "GUI" script under an interactive user session. The only solution I found so far is to use `PsExec` (with the `-i` parameter). That works (I see the PowerShell window pop up).

But I need to transmit the outputs of this "GUI" script to the host of my remote script.  Ideally, that should happen asynchronously during that the "GUI" script is running (i.e. without waiting for it to finish).

Is there a way to redirect the script output/error streams from the new powershell process to the caller powershell process?

---

**CODE:**

Remote script returning outputs to C# host asynchrounously (via a Pipeline):

```
Write-Output "Starting remote script..." # this string is transmitted to host
# Run interactiveScript.ps1 in other session using PsExec:
$EncodedCommand = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('& "interactiveScript.ps1" -myArg1 "abc"'))
$CommandString = "-accepteula -nobanner -i 1 -u admin -p admin -h \\localhost cmd /c `"echo . | powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand $EncodedCommand`"
$Result = Start-Process -FilePath $PsExecExecutable -ArgumentList $CommandString -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru -RedirectStandardOutput $TempFileNameSTDOUT -RedirectStandardError $TempFileNameSTDERR -ErrorAction Continue"
```

Interactive script `interactiveScript.ps1` that should redirect all its outputs/errors to calling script, which transmits them asynchronously to C# host:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$myArg1
)
Write-Output "Starting interactive script..." # this string must be transmitted to host
Write-Error "This is an error" # this error must be transmitted to host
Sleep 1 # Here the user interacts with the script
[System.Drawing.Bitmap]$img = ... # Here the script takes a screenshot of a window
Write-Output ([string](MyImageSerialization($img)) # this string must be transmitted to host
```

*Note*: I can't transmit directly an object such as [System.Drawing.Bitmap] to the host because it is a reference so I will serialize it to a string. Therefore it is acceptable if the solution works only for string outputs and errors.

---

**POSSIBLE CLUE:**

I am thinking about using named pipes to communicate between processes. But I don't know how to redirect the powershell streams through the pipes.

Comment: Hi, You've asked for a lot of things, but haven't provided any example code or really adequately explained what you want to do. I would strongly advise you to create an example script and raise each issue independently as it occurs, showing what your script actually does and then what you would like the output to be. Bonus points for readouts of the example objects. Hope that helps!

Comment: `psexec.exe` returns string output, not PowerShell objects.